# what will happen if i supply 12v with stall current of 3 amps dc motor with 24volt and limit the current at 1 amp?

Tags: dc-motor

I have 12 volt dc motor with 3 amp stall current 133 rpm and 8.8 kgf tourque.

I supply the motor with 12 volts and when I measure its current it was 2 amps with 133 rpm. I need to make it faster as I use it to drive a smal rc car.

What will happen if I supply the motors with 24 volts and limit the current at 1 amp during the straight parts of the race (when I need speed), and during the normal parts of the race I use 12 volts and 2 amps to supply the motor?

Comment: Is this your motor?http://store.fut-electronics.com/collections/motors/products/dc-geared-motor-with-metal-gear-8-8kg-250rpm-12v

Answer (score 1):

Run it at 24V on the straights but don't limit the current, just monitor it. The heat dissipation from current is (mostly) independent of voltage, so 2A should be as safe at 24V as it is at 12V.

However if the motor bogs down and stalls, either from friction (are those bearings seizing) or excess load (carpet, gravel or a steep hill) it could draw double the stall current and die immediately. So monitor the current and, if it approaches 2A (or say, 1.5A for more than a few seconds) drop back to 12V.

Now I said "mostly" above. There is also heat dissipated in the brushes, and at double the rated speed, these experience much more friction, sparking, heat and wear. So expect reduced life - maybe 10s of hours rather than thousands. Brushes are replaceable on some motors - so keep spares. Eventually the commutator will wear out.

Bearings and mechanicals are probably OK, unless they are the lowest grade of construction (cheapest). Look at similar size BLDC motors, you'll probably find them spinning at 30000rpm not 9000, with similar materials and bearings.

Answer (score 0):

Volts is speed, current is torque.

In principle, what you suggest is plausible **if** 1 Amp will give you enough torque to overcome wind resistance on the straight part of the race. Remember that wind resistance increases as the square of the speed.

Go ahead and try it out. What will happen is the motor will 'try' to run at 24v speed, and draw the current that's necessary to give enough torque to do so. If that's less than 1A, then good. If that's more than 1A, then what will happen depends on exactly how your 'limit' works.

Answer (score 0):

What will happen is that the current limiter will eat up a lot of the voltage meant for the motor and the motor will slow down.

Answer (score 0):

that could work, watch the current through the the motor and when it drops below 1A switch to 24V@1A, then watch the voltage and when it drops below 12V switch back to 12v@2A

Answer (score 0):

The motor is geared wit 1:34 ratio, means at output 133rpm the motor spins at 4500rpm, with doubling the voltage it will reach 9000rpm. The gearbox and rotor probably isn't made for such speed and it will fall appart. Anyway you can try to connect directly to 24V if you wish to have such speed, with current limitation you will limit the torque only, this won't prevent from protecting the motor from destructive centrifugal force, so it's basicaly the same if you connect directly to 24V.